# How to sort a result and display group wise

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

The mysql query is returning the below result.

```
id - name - class
1  - A  -    5
2  - D  -    1
3  - B  -    5
4  - c  -    1
5  - E  -    5
```

(class wise ordering is not possible as order has been applied on id)

Now, i want to display the view according to class wise like below

```
Class 1         Class 5
id - name       id - name  
2  - D          1  - A
4  - C          3  - B
                5  - E
```

So, i followed the below steps.

1) Created two separate arrays using array_push()

```
array_push($class_array, $class);  // indicates the class
array_push($other_array, $other); // $other indicates the string 'id - name';
```

2) asort($class_array);

**3) Executing the below foreach loop and i am stuck on this**

```
$new_c_array = array();
$table_array = array();

foreach ($class_array as $key => $val) {

 if (in_array($key, $new_c_array)) {

    $view_val = $other_array[$key];

    //**I am stuck in this section**
    // trying to find the next key from $class_array and check whether it is same of current key
    // if same then, its fine
    // else $view_val .= '</table>'

    array_push($table_array, $view_val);

 } else {


    array_push($new_c_array, $val);


    $view_val = '<table>';
    $view_val .= '<tr>';
    $view_val .= '<td> Class' . $val . '</td>';
    $view_val .= '</tr>';

    $view_val .= $other_array[$key];

    array_push($table_array, $view_val);


 }
}
```

**Question:**

1) How can i find the next key within that loop?

2) Is there any better way to accomplish the goal?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
//you array from DB
$dataArray=array(
        1 => array(
                'name'  =>  A,
                'class' =>  5
            ),
        2 => array(
                'name'  =>  D,
                'class' =>  1
            ),
        3 => array(
                'name'  =>  B,
                'class' =>  5
            ),
        4 => array(
                'name'  =>  C,
                'class' =>  1
            ),
        5 => array(
                'name'  =>  E,
                'class' =>  5
            )
    );
$resultArray=array();
foreach($dataArray as $key=>$value){
    $resultArray[$value['class']][]=array(
                        'name'  => $value['name'],
                        'id'    => $key
                    );
}
print_r($resultArray);
```

Comment: Hi, i am not sure what you wanted to mention. But i can see you used an array format $dataArray. I am getting an output (mysql result) which is mention at top (id-name-class relation).

Comment: Can you provide you array returned from query?